# Mail command using for loop not reliable?

Tags: linux, mailx

I have a test email account environment that I'm trying to fill with emails before running migrating tests. I've been trying to achieve this with the following bash script:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do
   echo "Test" | mail -s "Test Message $i" "myusername@gmail.com"
   sleep 0.1
done
```

However, only three emails actually arrived. I'm using an cloud server running Linux. Is this a security feature of `mailx`?

Comment: you're not check the status of `mail` for errors, or maybe instead use `mailq` or appropriate to see what is in the mail queue on the host in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If running the loop did not produce errors, then you should assume that every mail was at least queued for sending on your local system.

Depending on how your mail system is configured, it may limit the number of mail sent at once. The receiving system may also implement rate limiting measures.

In short, investigate if the messages have left your system yet. You may see the local mail queue with the `mailq` command (on most systems, there may be differences depending on what mailer software is in use). Messages in the mail queue are often processed periodically.

Since the target address is a Gmail account, you may also want to check the spam folder there.

Comment: Thanks! `mailq` was what I needed, the emails took a few hours and then went out. Didn't realize that the mail queue doesn't process them in order..